# To Check Dateformat in selenium rc

Tags: java, selenium

I am struggling in the below code. In the webpage some of the document are displayed in the grid. I am selecting first row, then I want check whether it displays date & time format as per the standard.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
Date date = new Date();

String newDate = dateFormat.format(date);

// This xpath for selecting first row on the grid
if(!selenium.getText("//*@id='gbs_evo_grid__TreeView_1']/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]").equals(newDate))
{
    SeleneseTestBase.fail("The Date format is not correct");
}
```

Can you help me whether the above code is correct or can you give alternate code for that.

Answer (score 1):

`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa`: You're using `m` for month, instead of `M`.

Moreover, your code checks that the date in the page is exactly the same as the current date (with second precision). Is this really what you need? If the server generating the page doesn't have exactly the ssame date as the client executing the test, or if the test is a bit slow, the test will never pass. Don't you simply want to check that the generated date is parsable with the date format (and, potentially, that its value is in the same minute or hour as the current date)?

Comment: s i want whhether generated date is parsable with date format.

Comment: can you suggest the code for checking dateformat. Then i want check whether generated date is parsable within the format or not

Comment: get the date string, parse it with the date format, and check that it doesn't throw any exception.